EKS:Create Cluster -- ClientException: You are not allowed to pass the role
EKS:Create Cluster -- ClientException: You are not allowed to pass the role
I'm facing an error when I create a resource with Tofu. I've checked all policies, and no one policy denied the request.
POLICY
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/eks.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKS",
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/eks-nodegroup.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

ERR LOG
2024-12-04T18:32:36.369+0700 [ERROR] vertex "aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster-dev-eks_private_cluster-global-cluster" error: creating EKS Cluster (eks_cluster-dev-eks_private_cluster-global-cluster): operation error EKS: CreateCluster, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: b65f2c83-6dfe-407c-ae4c-c6f2acc80155, ClientException: You are not allowed to pass the role arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/aws-service-role/eks.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKS

